# How to register a SIGINT handler that will run as soon as Ctrl+C is pressed?

Tags: python, signals, core-foundation, pyobjc, runloop

I am writing a Python script that uses the PyObjC bindings for AppKit. The script registers an observer with the shared [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace?language=objc)'s [`notificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1525071-notificationcenter?language=objc) and then calls AppKit.CFRunLoopRun() in order for the notifications to be processed:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from AppKit import *
import signal

shared_workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()

def on_did_activate_application(notification):
    print('on_did_activate_application(notification = %s)' % notification)

notification_center = shared_workspace.notificationCenter()
did_activate_application_observer = notification_center.addObserverForName_object_queue_usingBlock_(
        NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification,
        None,
        None,
        on_did_activate_application)

def handle_interrupt(signum, frame):
    notification_center.removeObserver_(did_activate_application_observer)
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_interrupt)

CFRunLoopRun()
```

The problem I am experiencing (reproducible with the above MCVE) is that, when I press Ctrl+C on the terminal window running the script, handle_interrupt() is not executed immediately, but rather it executes the next time a `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` notification is handled.

How do I respond to Ctrl+C / SIGINT just as soon as it occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting a "signal wakeup fd" to the write end of a pipe, and then creating a [`CFFileDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cffiledescriptor?language=objc) that monitors the read end of the pipe for activity.

As mentioned at [What’s New in Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html), in Python 2.6, a new API was added to the `signal` module called [set_wakeup_fd()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.set_wakeup_fd). Whenever a signal is received, a NUL byte (`'\0'`) is written to the fd.

If the wakeup fd is set to the write end of a pipe, then a `CFFileDescriptor` can be created to monitor for activity (availability of data) on the read end of the pipe, and callbacks on such activity can be configured to run on the `CFRunLoop`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from AppKit import * # For development only. This takes a long time to complete as there are many symbols.
import fcntl
import os
import signal

shared_workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()

def on_did_activate_application(notification):
    print('on_did_activate_application(notification = %s)' % notification)

notification_center = shared_workspace.notificationCenter()
did_activate_application_observer = notification_center.addObserverForName_object_queue_usingBlock_(
        NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification,
        None,
        None,
        on_did_activate_application)

def handle_signal(signum, frame):
    print('handle_signal(signum = %s, frame = <scrubbed>)' % signum)
    if signum == signal.SIGCONT:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handle_signal)
    elif signum == signal.SIGINT:
        notification_center.removeObserver_(did_activate_application_observer)
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())
    else:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377773/proper-way-to-handle-signals-other-than-sigint-in-python
        signal.signal(signum, signal.SIG_DFL)
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signum)

r, w = os.pipe()

flags = fcntl.fcntl(r, fcntl.F_GETFL, 0)
fcntl.fcntl(r, fcntl.F_SETFL, flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

def callout(f, call_back_types, info):
    # Note: The signal handler will run first.

    print('callout()')

    # Clear the pipe of NUL bytes.
    n = 0
    while True:
        try:
            n += len(os.read(r, 100))
        except OSError:
            break
    print('read %d byte(s)' % n)

    # Per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cffiledescriptor?language=objc
    # "Each call back is one-shot, and must be re-enabled if you want to get another one."
    # Thus we need to re-enable call backs.
    CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(f, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack)

file_descriptor = CFFileDescriptorCreate(None, r, True, callout, None)
CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(file_descriptor, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack)
run_loop_source = CFFileDescriptorCreateRunLoopSource(None, file_descriptor, 0)
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), run_loop_source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)

signal.set_wakeup_fd(w)
signal.signal(signal.SIGCONT, handle_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handle_signal)

# For testing, configure a SIGALRM to be received every two seconds.
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, lambda _1, _2: print('SIGALRM'))
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 2, 2)

print('about to call CFRunLoopRun()')
CFRunLoopRun()
```

Acknowledgments

A big thank you to 'A GUEST' (whoever you are) for posting [this paste on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/e1V4qycB); to Da_Blitz for writing the [Fighting set_wakeup_fd](http://www.pocketnix.org/doc/Fighting_set__wakeup__fd/) article; and to the askers/answerers of [“Proper” way to handle signals other than SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13377773/196844), [What's the difference between SIGSTOP and SIGTSTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11886812/196844), and [python Non-block read file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30172428/196844) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. It's effectively made my script not respond to \^Z *or* \^C.